# Nuget Configuration in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, nuget-package-restore, dnu

In our existing solution we have a NuGet.Config file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration>   
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />           
    </solution>
    <config>
        <add key="repositorypath" value="NuGetPackages" />
    </config> 
</configuration>
```

With this config we tell NuGet to store all packages in the "NuGetPackages" folder. This works fine for all our existing Projects (WebApi, Libraries, ...), but if I add a new ASP.NET Core project, the packages are stored in the `C:\Users\<username>\.dnx\packages` folder.

Is there a way to change the package folder on solution level?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you can use the `global.json` for that:

```
{
  "packages": "NuGetPackages",
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}
```

See: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Package-Locations

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `globalPackagesFolder` instead of `repositoryPath` key as stated [in NuGet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file):

> Note: `dependencyVersion` and `repositoryPath` apply only to projects using `packages.config`. `globalPackagesFolder` applies only to projects using `project.json` and projects using the new Visual Studio 2017 project format.