# How to dotnet build with local packages on windows build server

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using Team City to build a ASP.NET Core (target .NET) project. Dependency packages are deployed to the build server along with the project following this folder structure:

- Packages
- SolutionName

  - src

    - myproj.xproj

I have a nuget.config file with `<add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\..\packages"/>`

This corectly restores packages in VS and references seem to hold on build.
However, on the build server, **dotnet build** doesn't find the dependencies.

> Error NU1001: The dependency ... could not be resolved

Is there any way to specify the relative path of dependencies for dotnet build?

Comment: Slightly different approach -- how about running your own local nuget repository?

Comment: do you restore packages on the build server before trying to build them?

Comment: All packages are copied over to the build server before the build. The problem is in configuring the reference path for the .xproj

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040678/nuget-configuration-in-asp-net-core-1-0/36041287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Axel's comment and [Nuget Configuration in ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040678/nuget-configuration-in-asp-net-core-1-0/36041287)

Added a global.json file in the src folder with content:

```
{ "packages": "../../Packages" }
```